# ExpandableList vem oculto inicialmente

Tags: android

Toda vez que inicio a activity com o ExpandableList vem oculto, ai tenho que pressionar o botão de desligar e religar para então ele mostrar.

Como resolvo isso?

meu ExpandableList

```
<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

EDIÇÃO

Todo o meu Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorCorpo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="ham.org.br.nutricao.activity.CardapioActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarCardapio"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lvExp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_acao"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.cardapio_activity);
     expListView = ( ExpandableListView ) findViewById( R.id.lvExp );
     toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById( R.id.toolbarCardapio );
     toolbar.setTitle( "Cardápio" );
     setSupportActionBar( toolbar );

     listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter( this, listGrupo, listaItem );
     //setando list adapter
     expListView.setAdapter( listAdapter );
     int idTipoRef = bundle.getInt( "tipo" );
     String data   = bundle.getString( "data" );
     chamarTipoPratos( service, idTipoRef, data );

}

private void chamarTipoPratos( Service service, int idTipoRef, String data ){
        listGrupo = new ArrayList<String>();
        listaItem = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        listIngredientes = new HashMap<String, String>();
        listIngrediente = new ArrayList<String>();
        final Call<List<TipoPrato>> listTipoPratos = service.getlistTipoPratos("R", idTipoRef, data);
        listTipoPratos.enqueue( new Callback<List<TipoPrato>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<TipoPrato>> call, Response<List<TipoPrato>> response) {
           //     Log.i("onResponse TipoPratos",response.toString());

                if( response.isSuccessful() ){
                    List<TipoPrato> tipoPratos = response.body();
                    int i = 0;
                    for( TipoPrato tipoPrato : tipoPratos ){

                        //Log.i("Tipo", tipoPrato.getTipoprato());
                        ArrayList<Prato> listaPratos = tipoPrato.getPratoList();

                        listGrupo.add(tipoPrato.getTipoprato());
                        ArrayList<String> pratos = new ArrayList<String>();
                        ArrayList<String> ingredientes = new ArrayList<String>();

                        for ( Prato prato : listaPratos ){
                       //     Log.i("Pratos", prato.getPrato());
                            pratos.add( prato.getPrato() );
                            ingredientes.add( prato.getIngrediente() );
                            listIngredientes.put( prato.getPrato(), prato.getIngrediente() );
                        }

                        listaItem.put( listGrupo.get( i ), pratos );

                        i++;

                }

            }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<TipoPrato>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("onFailure TipoPrato", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Que botão é esse de "botão desligar e religar"?

Comment: O botão do celular. Aquele que bloqueia a tela

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vi três opções que podem estar fazendo isso acontecer, provavelmente a visibilidade do layout pai está como gone ou invisible, pode possuir algum layout por cima da View,ou a inicialização da ExpandableListView ou do layout pai dentro da activity ou fragment, está sendo gone ou invisible.

Comment: como eu encontro isso?

Comment: Verifica em seu XML qual a View pai ou então reedita seu post escrevendo todo o XML da ExpandableListView

Comment: Já editei com todo o xml da activity

Comment: Poderia colcoar seu código tambem ? Remova o Weigth, pois não é necessário divisão.

Comment: Coloquei o codigo no geral

Comment: Certo, não está aparecendo nada, simplesmente porque você não está referenciando seu layout, para isso você tem que sobreescrever o método onCreate. Abaixo do onCreate você adiciona essa duas linhas de código super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.nomedoseulayout); //Coloca o nome do seu layout aqui para ele ser referenciado, onde está R.layout.nomedoseulayout você coloca o layout que está usando o ExpandableList

Comment: Fiz uma nova edição pra mostrar o como está o início do meu onCreate

Comment: Está funcionamento normalmente, só que no início ele vem como se fosse oculto, ai se eu pressionar o botão de bloquear a tela do celular e desbloquear a tela, ele aparece

Comment: Alguma ideia do que possa ser?

Comment: Pode mostrar a parte do código de "Ligar" e "Desligar" o botão no click ?

Comment: era o botão do celular mesmo

Comment: Maravilha =) bom que resolveu seu problema.

Comment: na verdade eu tinha que chamar o  chamarTipoPratos( service, idTipoRef, data ); dentro do proprio metodo e eu estava chamando após a chamada do método